# How to plot different graphs for different sheets from excel workbook using matplotplib?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have excel in which 3 different sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) having 2 columns each X, Y.

[image]

I want to plot 3 different graphs for these three respective sheets.
How can I plot them using Pandas and Matplotlib in PYthon?

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` package has both Excel reading *and* plotting capabilities. One possible solution is as follows:

```
# Read all sheets of the workbook
sheets = pd.read_excel("/path/to/your/datafile.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
for sheet_name, df in sheets.items():
    df.plot(x='x', y='y', title=sheet_name)
```

This gave me a sequence of images looking like this one (but with other sheet titles - I duplicated the data on three sheets).

[image]

If you just wanted specific sheetnames you could follow the `read_excel` call with

```
for sheet_name in ("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"):
    df = sheet[sheet_name]
    df.plot(x='x', y='y', title=sheet_name)
```

**EDIT:** The questioner reports that the particular file in question was successfully processed with the following code.

```
for i in range(3):
   df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=i)
   f = Figure(figsize=(3, 2), dpi=100)
   a = f.add_subplot(111)
   a.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'ro')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer !  Below code I have written to get 3 different graphs


for i in range(3):
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=i)

        f = Figure(figsize=(3, 2), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 'ro')

Comment: Always nice to get positive feedback, thanks. I've added your code to the answer.